# reactjs useState array of objects Map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I creating an online shopping site using `reactjs` (using react functional components). so the customer can add multiple products to the shopping cart.

Can get different qty of a product. When the user click "add to cart" button that specific product details add to the data layer (I use context `api` on `react`).

If user increase a product qty it will add as a new product to the data layer;

after adding products to the cart user can then click "Proceed to checkout" then user will redirect to
payment page. In that, I retrieve all the products details which user added to the cart using **'useEffect'** and store it on a *useState* ('purchaseItem' is the useState that I use for that)

This is the data object that I retrieve using `useEffect`
('pid' means product id )

```
 [
      {
    
        availability: true
        brand: "MSI"
        pid: 3
        price: 350698
      },
      {
    
        availability: true
        brand: "MSI"
        pid: 3
        price: 350698
      },
       {
    
        availability: true
        brand: "MSI"
        pid: 4
        price: 350698
      }
    
    ]
```

I want to create a new array using this array like this. and store in on "purchaseDetails" `useState`
this is the output that I want
(qty means how many times that element appears. product id can use to identify objects)

```
   [
    
      {
        
       item:{
                availability: true
                brand: "MSI"
                pid: 3
                price: 350698
    
            },
       qty:2
    
      },
    
      {
        
       item:{
                availability: true
                brand: "MSI"
                pid: 4
                price: 350698
    
            },
       qty:1
    
      }
    
    ]
```

This is payment component code

```
 import {useStateValue} from '../states/StateProvider'
    import {getBasketitemqty } from "../states/reducer";
    
        function Payment() {
        
          
            const [state,dispatch] = useStateValue();
        
            const [purchaseItem,setpurchaseItem] = useState([]);
        
            const [purchaseDetails,setpurchaseDetails] = useState([]);
        
            const key = "pid";
        
            useEffect(() => {
                
                setpurchaseItem([...new Map(state.basket.map((item) => [item[key], item])).values()]);
//this code will retrieve all the unique products which user add to cart 
               
          
              }, [state.basket]);


            const testrqeust = ()=>{

             purchaseItem.forEach(item => setpurchaseDetails(prevState => ([{
            ...prevState, 
            item:item,
            itemqty:getBasketitemqty(state.basket,item.pid),
        
        }])));
                 
         /*this getBasketitemqty function takes two parameters those are state and the product id and it gives the qty which user want from that specific product*/

            }
        
         
        
          return (
            <div className="payment container">
        
                <button onClick={testrqeust} className="btn btn-lg btn-info">Confirm Order</button>
               
             
            </div>
          );
        }
        
        export default Payment;
```

how can set 'purchaseDetails' `useState` with the output that I want when user click a "Confirm Order" button?

Comment: Update your question to show what you have tried

Comment: I updated it. can you please read it again. (useEffect and testrqeust functions code updated)

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is related to the button, your onClick should be something like

```
onClick={e => testRequest(e)}
```

and then testRequest would be something like

```
    const testRequest = (e) => { 
       setPurchaseDetails(e.target.value)
    }
```

In this e.target is your button, and you can get properties from it like `e.target.value` or `e.target.id` which returns these properties from the button. You can try `e.target.whatever` to get whatever property from the button.

---

It's kinda hard to tell what you want though. You should specify what you want to set the purchaseDetails to.

Here's a few modern javascript courses for learning so more javascript tricks and syntax

https://scrimba.com/learn/es6
https://scrimba.com/learn/introtoes6

Comment: can you please read quesiton again. i mention the data i got from the data layer
i want to create a new array with that data. i mention all the data format

Comment: thank you for your reply. i updated the question again. the problem is there is a array of objects that i got from data layer. i want to create a new array from that. i mention the output that i want . please check it again

Answer (score 0):

This logic will work for you, just integrate in your code block

```js
var array = [
      {
        availability: true,
        brand: "MSI",
        pid: 3,
        price: 350698
      },
      {
    
        availability: true,
        brand: "MSI",
        pid: 3,
        price: 350698
      },
       {
    
        availability: true,
        brand: "MSI",
        pid: 4,
        price: 350698
      }
];

var dataToSend = array.reduce((acc, value) => {
    const item = acc.find(d => d.item.pid === value.pid);
    if (item) {
        item.qty++;
    } else {
       acc.push({ item: value, qty: 1 });
    }
    return acc;
  }, []);

console.log(dataToSend);
```

Comment: thank you. but i want to implement that code with useState. i want to store that data on a useState